# Pattern replace in R

Tags: regex, r, twitter

I'm working on a Twitter dataset in R and I'm finding it difficult to remove usernames from tweets.

This is an example of the tweets in the tweet column of my dataset:

```
[1] "@danimottale: 2 bad our inalienable rights offend their sensitivities. U cannot reason with obtuse zealotry. // So very well said."         
[2] "@FreeMktMonkey @drleegross Want to build HSA throughout lifetime for when older thus need HDHP not to deplete it if ill before 65y/o.thanks"
```

I want to remove/replace all words starting with "@" to get this output:

```
[1] "2 bad our inalienable rights offend their sensitivities. U cannot reason with obtuse zealotry. // So very well said."         
[2] "Want to build HSA throughout lifetime for when older thus need HDHP not to deplete it if ill before 65y/o.thanks"
```

This gsub function works for just removing the "@" symbol.

```
gsub("@", "", tweetdata$tweets)
```

I want to say, remove characters following text symbol until you encounter a space or punctuation mark.

I started trying to just deal with space but to no avail:

```
gsub("@.*[:space:]$", "", tweetdata$tweets)
```

this removes the second tweet entirely

```
gsub("@.*[:blank:]$", "", tweetdata$tweets)
```

this doesn't change the output.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following. `\S+` matches any *non-whitespace* character (`1` or more times), followed by matching a single *whitespace* character.

```
gsub('@\\S+\\s', '', noRT$text)
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/al2XQs)

**EDIT:** A negated match would work fine also (using just the *space character*)

```
gsub('@[^ ]+ ', '', noRT$text)
```

Comment: Many thanks - very helpful, too bad I cannot vote it up because I'm new.

Comment: @user3722736 You can check this solution if it fits your needs though by clicking the checkmark to the left below the up vote count.

Comment: Use `sub` rather than `gsub` since there is only one substitution.

Comment: There are multiple in the second string.

Answer (score 1):

The regex approach here is easy and straight forward.  I'm adding a second option that allows you remove text between any 2 boundaries using qdap's the `genX` function.  This allows you to supply a left and right boundary.

```
library(qdap)
genX(x, "@", "\\s")

## [1] "2 bad our inalienable rights offend their sensitivities. U cannot reason with obtuse zealotry. // So very well said."
## [2] "Want to build HSA throughout lifetime for when older thus need HDHP not to deplete it if ill before 65y/o.thanks"
```

Comment: Thank you, it's great to see another solution. I wish I could vote your answer up but I've got no reputation yet.